# Connecting Google Analytics with Custom Search Engine AdSense

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, google-custom-search

I have a Custom Search Engine that I've created with AdSense. I've put that search engine as a site search in my Google Sites page. I've connected both the Custom Search Engine and the Google Site to my Analytics page via their settings pages.

Now, I'm trying to get Analytics to show me the AdSense for Search statistics. I've managed to connect the Google Sites page, to the Analytics, and I can see the search statistics in the Analytics as well. But I can't get it to show the actual AdSense for Search statistics from the Custom Search Engine.

How can I configure everything so I can get the AdSense for Search statistics of my Custom Search Engine in my Analytics page?

Comment: Your question might be better off at [webmasters.se].